# How to detect swipe using iscroll5

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll

Is it possible to detect swipe using iscroll5. I am using this http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/ and it is ok, but there is one line of code

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Which prevents swipe detection. It there a function which is able to detect swipe and allow scrolling with iscroll?

I am also using jquery mobile latest version

Comment: Its not an Iscroll issue. Drop down to JQM 1.4.3 and see if the swipe issue is gone. The last JQM versions from testing have issues on android. alternatively try hammer JS or touchswipe js to handle your swipes.

Comment: I have found solution somewhere, when I added some code to my javascript it fixed swiping issue

    $.extend($.event.special.swipe,{
   scrollSupressionThreshold: 10, // More than this horizontal displacement, and we will suppress scrolling.
   durationThreshold: 1000, // More time than this, and it isn't a swipe.
   horizontalDistanceThreshold: 30,  // Swipe horizontal displacement must be more than this.
   verticalDistanceThreshold: 75,  // Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.
 });

Just add it somewhere before using swipe detection, it works with 1.4.5. jquery mobile

Comment: can you post the exact code you got the swipes to work on Android in the question so i can test them? also what android version are you working on?

Comment: This is Android 4.4.2. I am using that code I have paste it comment before. Just put it before swipe function